# XCode assistant editor doesn't show my .h and my related .cpp file

Tags: c++, xcode

If I create .cpp file from xcode, it will create .h file for me automatically, and I will be able to view two files together in Assistant Editor. It will show .h file relate to .cpp file right next to each other.

However, I create my project from TextMate and import those files manually. Now, when I click .h file it won't show the related cpp file right next to it. How can I make that happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmmm.. I tried to recreate your problem, but it worked for me.

I have two thoughts:

1) Are you sure they are named the same thing? If not, it doesn't seem to consider them counterparts.
2) When you've switched to the Assistant Editor, to the right of the back/forward buttons is a dropdown menu to select which file to display. This should be set to "Counterparts" in order to get it to auto-display the correct counterpart.

If you have this set to manual, you can set it to maintain a certain file on the side.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it again, and actually from that problem I change to IntelliJ instead. :-)

Comment: Mine accidentally got stuck in "Manual" mode and I couldn't figure out how to change it back. Turns out the "Counterparts" submenu is actually selectable, which sets it back.

Answer (score 5):

Go into Xcode (v4) Organizer...Choose Projects.
Find your project and delete the Derived Data. Then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose you view and in the Utilities View, in the Identity Inspector tab, In the Class text field, put down your class name.

   [image]
2. Save
3. The relevant class will appear in the assistent editor.